# Can't access integer in xml file?

Tags: android, android-xml

xml file in res/xml/sizes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name = "size1">0</integer>
    <integer name = "size2">1</integer>
    <integer name = "size3">2</integer>
</resources>
```

In my java file, I'm trying to access the integer by doing

```
private int sizeState = R.xml.sizes.size1;
```

This gives the error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'size1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access interger value from xml file, do like this :

```
Resources res = getResources();
int sizeState = res.getInteger(R.integer.size1);
```

Please make sure your file location in : `res/values/sizes.xml`

Refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer

Comment: Any have error ? Do you try to show **sizeState** in Log

Comment: it appears I am able to reference it when I move it to the values folder but for some reason its showing up as 2131427335 when i print size1 which I declared as 0.

Comment: @JasonDD , are you use Activity or Fragment or Fragment activity ? , if use Fragment, you can try ```getActivity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.size1)```

Comment: I'm using a service and I fixed the integer value problem. However, I still can't reference it unless it is in the values folder. If I put it in the xml folder, I'm not sure how to reference it.

Comment: @JasonDD Yup, all resource file in android must be declare in ```res/values/``` folder. If out of scope, ***R*** can't refer that value. If the answer is accepted, please approve it.

Comment: Alright I have one more thing. Since I moved it to the values folder, how would i access the integer from an xml file in the xml folder? If I do android:keyboardMode="@sizes/size1", it does not work.

Comment: Are you try **android:keyboardMode="@integer/size1"** @JasonDD

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  int size= this.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.size1);
```

Comment: It does not work unless the xml file is in the values folder. I'm trying to access it from the xml folder.